# Is Entity Framework EDMX file provider specific?

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4.1, sql-server-ce-4

I wan't to use Sql Server 2008 as production environment with provider System.Data.SqlClient and Sql Server compact 4.0 with provider System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0 for integration testing with SpecFlow.

Is it possible to use the same edmx file in Entity Framework for the different environments?
In case of Yes as an answer, how can I split the EDMX and keep different mappings?

I already have the production environment working with Sql Server 2008 and have generated a Sql Server compact 4.0 file (.sdf) from the Entity Model but when i try to connect to the compact database it gives me various errors.

I found this line in my EDMX file: 
`Provider="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will be possible to use SQL CE, if you change the values as folows:

```
Provider="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" ProviderManifestToken="4.0"
```